# Nested Dictionary Comprehension from a List of Lists in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

edgeList is a list of lists

I have this working but its slower than I want:

```
for rowIndex, rowVal in enumerate(edgeList):
    for colIndex, colVal in enumerate(rowVal):
        EdgeDict[rowIndex][colIndex] = colVal
```

Would it be faster using dict comprehension?  I tried, but got tangled up in the syntax

Comment: update the question with an excerpt of edgeList?

Comment: Why create the dictionary **at all**? You already get the same indexing *with your existing list*. `edgeList[rowIndex][colIndex]` maps to `colVal`.

Comment: Marijn, I don't have a choice - the result is getting fed into a function that requires it to be a dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comprehension like this should do it, but I doubt that it is significantly faster. Also, the accessing of values is the same as in the list you have:

```
edge_dict = {row: dict(enumerate(row_val)) for row, row_val in enumerate(edgeList)}
```

Comment: Thanks this did speed it up some

Answer (score 1):

There is very little point in doing this. You *already have a map from coordinate pair to value*. Your `edgeList` is that map:

```
edgeList[integer_value_for_row][integer_value_for_col]
```

maps to your values.

You can produce your dictionary with:

```
{row_index: dict(enumerate(row)) for row_index, row in enumerate(edgeList)}
```

This maps the result of `enumerate()` directly to a dictionary; there is no need to nest that loop.

Comment: I don't have a choice - the result is getting fed into a function that requires it to be a dict –

Comment: Why does that function require a dict? Is it expecting the data structure to be sparse? Why does the rest of your code require it to be a list, can it be retooled to use a sparse dict?

Comment: If you tell us more about that function and your use-case, perhaps we can offer better solutions?